# Enable PostgreSQL extensions in JDBC

Tags: spring, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc

I am using Spring + Tomcat8 together with PostgreSQL 9.2.
I installed the [Trigram](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html) extension on the database for improved searching in tables.

When I connect to my database manually, the following statement works:

```
SELECT id, name, similarity(name, 'a') FROM dev.customer WHERE name % 'a' ORDER BY similarity ;
```

However, when I try this in Spring using `jdbcTemplate.query()` I get an error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: function similarity(character varying, character varying) does not exist
```

When I remove the `similarity()` function and only use the `%` operator, I get the following exception:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying % character varying
```

It seems that the postgres jdbc driver needs to be configured in order to support non-standard syntax: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/ext.html

The `server.xml` of my tomcat installation contains the following resource:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/NasPostgresDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="usr" password="pwd"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/dbname"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
          maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
```

which should be correct: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/load.html

What exacly do I need to do to make trigram matching working?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are connecting to the same database using the same user?

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz Yes I am. I currently only have one database with one user.

Comment: Can you post results of `select 

current_database(),
current_schema(),
current_schemas(true),
current_user,
inet_client_addr(),
inet_client_port(),
inet_server_addr(),
inet_server_port(),
pg_my_temp_schema(),
pg_postmaster_start_time(),
session_user,
version();`

executed twice: once in psql and once from java code from your application?

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz Result from *psql*: `"sapling ,  , {pg_catalog} , postgres , 192.168.0.13 , 20290 , 192.168.0.3 , 5432 , 0 , "2015-05-21 12:00:20.422757+02" , postgres , "PostgreSQL 9.1.15 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu ,  compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2 ,  64-bit""` Result from *java*: `sapling , , {pg_catalog} , postgres , 192.168.0.13 , 19955 , 192.168.0.3 , 5432 , 0 , "2015-05-21 12:00:20.422757+02" , postgres , "PostgreSQL 9.1.15 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu , compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2 , 64-bit"`

Comment: I am using the `JDBC41 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4-1201` driver from the postgres HP: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: If you are using same database with same user, I can only imagine a schema problem. What gives (under psql) `\df+ similarity` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I only have 1 schema and actived the ext. with `SET SCHEMA 'dev'; CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;` Anyways, how should I execute `\df+ similarity`?

Comment: I assume the functions have been created in 'dev' schema. To confirm it, just open a psql session and just type `\df+ similarity` (+ return) in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, every object (be it a table, an index or a function) belongs to a *schema*. As you said in comment that you installed the extension with :

```
SET SCHEMA 'dev'; CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

I assume that the functions are accessible in *dev* shema.

If it is the case, you should be able to use them in JDBC that way :

```
SELECT id, name, dev.similarity(name, 'a') as similarity FROM dev.customer 
    WHERE name % 'a' ORDER BY similarity ;
```

Comment: Thanks! The similarity-function works. The `%` operator however doesn't. Is there a way to enable the extension globally? If not, how should the `%` operator work?

Comment: Use `ALTER EXTENSION pg_trgm SET SCHEMA pg_catalog;` to use it everywhere without referencing schema `dev`. This will also fix your problem with `%` operator.

Comment: It would be better ot use `alter user ... set search_path = ...` to include the schema that contains the extension in the default search path